# Groovy "No such property"

Tags: java, groovy

I'm using java to evaluate some expressions in Groovy.

If I try to evaluate a property that does not exist, I get:

> groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: "..." for class: Script .

How can I check if property exists with Java?  Or how should I handle this?

Some code:

```
<script>
 import com.dummy
 dummy = dummies.get(1)
</script>
```

I evaluate this with `GroovyShell.evaluate(script)`. Imagine dummy only has one property called 'name'. Then if I try to evaluate, for example, ${dummy.age}. I'll get the exception

Comment: What do you mean by "using Java to evaluate some expressions in Groovy"? Is that Groovy code or Java code? Show us what you run.

Comment: show this error to a person who has created a script...

Comment: Added some details. @ArvindKumarAvinash What is that object? The Object that evaluate returns does not have those methods

Comment: but what do you expect to see if there is not such property `age` ?

Comment: Nothing. I want to check if it exists before evaluating @daggett